# Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I tried to make connection with the api restcountries.eu.
My javascript code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
var arr = []
request.open('GET', 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/col', true)
request.onload = function () {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)

  data.forEach((countries) => {  
    arr.push(countries.name)
  })

  var selectBox = document.getElementById('test')
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    selectBox.options.add(new Option(arr[i], arr[i]));
  }     
}
    
request.send()
```

I recieve the following error: Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload on the line where I use the foreach function.
I parsed the data before so I don't get it where it went wrong.
Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Is the parsed data as array or object? Can you post the console output for `this. response`?

Comment: Please, use a debugger. Check if your assumptions about the data hold true, by looking at the variables in the debugger while you are stepping through your code. Then things will usually become clearer.

Comment: If I look at this URL I see the response is an object, not an array.

Comment: What is your expected result? The URL returns an object containing one country name for "Colombia", so what other countries do you expect to get in your array/what is the `arr` for?

Comment: The result should be the name of the country is shown in the selectBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data at the URL `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/col` is not an array, it is a JavaScript object. If you want to traverse it's properties with forEach you have to call something like `Object.keys` or `Array.from` on the parsed data, like

```
Object.keys(data).forEach((k) => {  
  arr.push(data[k].name)
})
```

Comment: `Array.from` won't do anything useful with that data.

Comment: @cherrydt true if it doesn't have indexed properties as well as length, just in general though

Comment: The error is gone at least, but now it returns a few times [object Object] in my array instead of the country names, am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: @saderk edited, if you don't want the objects you can just put the name in directly

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the values of the items from the data variable, then you should first convert the values into an array. To get an array of the values of the object, you can do something like this:

```
Object.values(data).forEach(item=>{
    arr.push(item.name);
});
```

Remember, **.forEach() only works for arrays**. So whenever you have an array of values, you can use `Object.values(yourObjectHere)` to get an array of its values. I think bluejayke mentioned that `Object.keys(yourObjectHere)` returns an array of its keys (properties).

Comment: If you go to ops url, its returning a payload for a specific country. Specifically a ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country. For each will never work for op because he needs a collection of countries, and he's specifically querying columbia.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying a specific country, specifically columbia. I think what your goal is, to create a list of options based on a list of countries. In that case, you will need to change your request url to `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2` to receive an entire list of countries that you can iterate over.